# Recursive Map function

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm having hard time figuring out how to do this recursive map function.
I have an array that look like this.

```
var array = [
      {
        id: 1,
        label: 'Satisfied customers',
        children: [
          {
            id: 2,
            label: 'Good food',
            icon: 'restaurant_menu',
            children: [

              { id: 3, label: 'Quality ingredients'},
              { id: 4, label: 'Good recipe' }
            ]
          },
          {
            id: 5,
            label: 'Good service',
            icon: 'room_service',
            children: [
              { id: 6, label: 'Prompt attention' },
              { id: 7, label: 'Professional waiter' }
            ]
          },
          {
            id: 8,
            label: 'Pleasant surroundings',
            icon: 'photo',
            children: [
              {
                id: 9,
                label: 'Happy atmosphere (not tickable)',
                tickable: false,
              },
              {
                id: 10,
                label: 'Good table presentation (disabled node)',
                disabled: true,
              },
              {
                id: 11,
                label: 'Pleasing decor',
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            id: 12,
            label: 'Extra information (has no tick)',
            noTick: true,
            icon: 'photo'
          },
          {
            id: 13,
            label: 'Forced tick strategy (to "strict" in this case)',
            tickStrategy: 'strict',
            icon: 'school',
            children: [
              {
                id: 14,
                label: 'Happy atmosphere',
              },
              {
                id: 15,
                label: 'Good table presentation',
              },
              {
                id: 16,
                label: 'Very pleasing decor',
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ];
```

This is the array looks like...
[image]

As you can see the children is `recursive`.

I need to put them into one array.
My code doesn't work an has an error.

```
const result = [];   
const map = (e) => {

    result.push({
        id: e.id,
        label: e.label,
    })

    e.children.map(map)


};

array.map(map);
```

the error is on `e.children.map(map)`.
[image]

I need to push them all in array variable but I don't know how to do this. TY

Comment: Please provide the expected output

Comment: You have to check whether the element you just pushed actually has `children`. At some point there are no children which leads to `e.children` being undefined thus causing the `...'map' of undefined' error.

Comment: The leaves of the tree don't appear to have a `children` property of their own, so you should check for its existence: `e.children && e.children.map(map)`.

Comment: because not every node has `children`, so you only run `map` function on those nodes that have a children.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to check if current item has `children` element, and you can use `forEach` instead because `map` return new array and `forEach` just go throw each element.

```
const cb = (e) => {
    res.push({
        id: e.id,
        label: e.label,
    });
    e.children && e.children.forEach(cb);
}
array.forEach(cb);
```

Comment: great solution. Simple and elegant

Answer (score 8):

A great way to learn about [mutual recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_recursion) using vanilla JavaScript -

```
const transform1 = ({ id = 0, label = "", children = [] }) =>
  [ { id, label }, ...transformAll (children) ] // calls transformAll

const transformAll = (children = []) =>
  children .flatMap (c => transform1 (c)) // calls transform1

console.log(transformAll(array))
```

Output -

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "label": "Satisfied customers"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "label": "Good food"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "label": "Quality ingredients"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "label": "Good recipe"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "label": "Good service"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "label": "Prompt attention"
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "label": "Professional waiter"
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "label": "Pleasant surroundings"
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "label": "Happy atmosphere (not tickable)"
  },
  {
    "id": 10,
    "label": "Good table presentation (disabled node)"
  },
  {
    "id": 11,
    "label": "Pleasing decor"
  },
  {
    "id": 12,
    "label": "Extra information (has no tick)"
  },
  {
    "id": 13,
    "label": "Forced tick strategy (to \"strict\" in this case)"
  },
  {
    "id": 14,
    "label": "Happy atmosphere"
  },
  {
    "id": 15,
    "label": "Good table presentation"
  },
  {
    "id": 16,
    "label": "Very pleasing decor"
  }
]
```

Expand the snippet below the verify the results in your own browser -

```js
var array = [
      {
        id: 1,
        label: 'Satisfied customers',
        children: [
          {
            id: 2,
            label: 'Good food',
            icon: 'restaurant_menu',
            children: [

              { id: 3, label: 'Quality ingredients'},
              { id: 4, label: 'Good recipe' }
            ]
          },
          {
            id: 5,
            label: 'Good service',
            icon: 'room_service',
            children: [
              { id: 6, label: 'Prompt attention' },
              { id: 7, label: 'Professional waiter' }
            ]
          },
          {
            id: 8,
            label: 'Pleasant surroundings',
            icon: 'photo',
            children: [
              {
                id: 9,
                label: 'Happy atmosphere (not tickable)',
                tickable: false,
              },
              {
                id: 10,
                label: 'Good table presentation (disabled node)',
                disabled: true,
              },
              {
                id: 11,
                label: 'Pleasing decor',
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            id: 12,
            label: 'Extra information (has no tick)',
            noTick: true,
            icon: 'photo'
          },
          {
            id: 13,
            label: 'Forced tick strategy (to "strict" in this case)',
            tickStrategy: 'strict',
            icon: 'school',
            children: [
              {
                id: 14,
                label: 'Happy atmosphere',
              },
              {
                id: 15,
                label: 'Good table presentation',
              },
              {
                id: 16,
                label: 'Very pleasing decor',
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ];
    
const transform1 = ({ id = 0, label = "", children = [] }) =>
  [ { id, label }, ... transformAll (children) ]
  
const transformAll = (children = []) =>
  children .flatMap (c => transform1 (c))
  
console.log(transformAll(array))
```

---

**A tour of Flat Earth**

If you've never seen `.flatMap` before -

```
xs.flatMap(f) == xs.map(f).reduce((a,b) => a.concat(b), [])
xs.flatMap(f) == xs.reduce((a,b) => a.concat(f(b)), [])
```

It's best seen with a simple demo -

```js
const twice = x =>
  [ x, x ]
  
console .log
  ( [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ] .flatMap (twice) // [ 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c' ]
  , [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ] .flatMap (twice) // [ 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5 ]
  )
```

`flatMap` is useful for all kinds of things -

```js
const tree =
  [ 0, [ 1 ], [ 2, [ 3 ], [ 4, [ 5 ] ] ] ]
  
const all = ([ value, ...children ]) =>
  [ value, ...children .flatMap (all) ]
  
console .log (all (tree))
// [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
```

really cool things -

```js
const ranks =
  [ 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A' ]
  
const suits =
  [ '♡', '♢', '♤', '♧' ]

const cards =
  ranks .flatMap (r =>
  suits .flatMap (s =>
  [ [ r, s ] ]
  ))

console .log (cards)
// [ ['J','♡'], ['J','♢'], ['J','♤'], ['J','♧']
// , ['Q','♡'], ['Q','♢'], ['Q','♤'], ['Q','♧']
// , ['K','♡'], ['K','♢'], ['K','♤'], ['K','♧']
// , ['A','♡'], ['A','♢'], ['A','♤'], ['A','♧']
// ]
```

Comment: You're a rockstar!

Comment: @Rbex I added some more `flatMap` examples :D